# App crashes by Resource$NotFoundException using ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library

My application crashes on start up with this log:

```
09-25 07:12:27.721: W/ResourceType(361): Failure getting entry for 0x7f030016 (t=2 e=22) in package 0: 0xffffffb5
09-25 07:12:27.721: D/AndroidRuntime(361): Shutting down VM
09-25 07:12:27.721: W/dalvikvm(361): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
09-25 07:12:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(361): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-25 07:12:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(361): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.villaparvaneh/com.villaparvaneh.VillaListActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030016
09-25 07:12:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-25 07:12:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-25 07:12:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-25 07:12:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-25 07:12:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-25 07:12:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-25 07:12:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-25 07:12:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-25 07:12:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-25 07:12:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-25 07:12:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-25 07:12:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-25 07:12:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(361): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030016
09-25 07:12:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:892)
09-25 07:12:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1869)
09-25 07:12:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:731)
09-25 07:12:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:318)
09-25 07:12:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
09-25 07:12:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:840)
09-25 07:12:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.setContentView(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:261)
09-25 07:12:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at com.villaparvaneh.VillaListActivity.onCreate(VillaListActivity.java:47)
09-25 07:12:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-25 07:12:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-25 07:12:27.741: E/AndroidRuntime(361):  ... 11 more
```

At first I used eclipse wizard for creating a Master/Detail activity and my `minsdk` was set to 11. but then I used `ActionBarSherlock` and changed my activity code for that nothing more! At first time lunch there was an error for not setting theme to `Theme.Sherlock.Light`. after I changed the style file the above error comes up!
I googled for a day and read some similar issues like [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/551) and [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/685), but it seems that my problem is not related to them. I searched for resource `0x7f030016` in `R.java` file and find out that it is `R.attr.actionModeCloseDrawable` and the exception is thrown in the `setContentView(int layoutResId)` of `ActionBarSherlockCompat.java` or `ActionBarSherlockNative.java` at the following line:

```
mActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResId, mContentParent);
```

where `layoutResId` is `R.attr.actionModeCloseDrawable` and `mContentParent` is an instance of `com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.widget.NineFrameLayout`. I spend a whole day on this and checked every related link on google, but I cant figure out what's happening. I use Android 4.3 for building the app and support library revision 18. I don't think my code is useful here because error is not happened in my code. maybe some of xml files in `res` folder is needed, just tell which one to add it.
Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: you should be inflating a layout with widgets. `R.layout.mylayout`  right?

Comment: yes, just in my fragment class. what is the problem? `View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_villa_list_dummy, container, false);`

Comment: @jake-wharton do you have any idea?